# django querying from 3 models

Tags: python, django, django-models

My models are :

model 1:

```
class source_of_enquiry(models.Model):
    source_of_enquiry = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.source_of_enquiry
```

model 2:

```
class customers(models.Model):
    cutomer_name = models.CharField(max_lentgth=200) 
    customer_src_n_type = models.Foreign_key(source_of_enquiry)
    customer_contact = models.CharField(max_lentgth=200) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.customer_name
```

model 3:

```
class sales_cycle(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    customer_name = models.Foreignkey(customers)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.item_name
```

how should i know how many sales had peen completed based on source of enquiry??

tried many from `select_related' and 'prefetch_selected' , but all were kaput.

Comment: Please paste your exact models.py it would be more helpful to preview the models.

Comment: You're not making sense. What's the question?

Comment: I have changed the question. and pasted the models

Comment: A foreignKey is to a different model, not a field on a different model.

Comment: Also `return '%s' % cutomer_name` should probably be `return '%s' % self.cutomer_name`....

Comment: hey thanks, pouting out, these were typing mistakes here , my actual model does not have these errors.

Comment: `"how many sales have been completed"` - how do you define a sale as being completed?

Comment: if an entry exists in sales_cycle, it means , the sale has been completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - python naming convention state that classes should not have underscores and prefer upper-case letters instead. So your models should be SourceEnquiry, Customer (not plural) and SaleCycle.

That being said, let's say I have a SourceEnquiry item (I'm going to pick one arbitrarily), and you want all related SaleCycle items, you do it like so:

```
>>> sinq = SourceEnquiry.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> SaleCycle.objects.all().filter(customer_name__customer_src_n_type=sinq)
```

**p.s.**

also, going back to the naming convention thing, it's redundant to use customer as part of a field name inside the class Customer. You alread know it's a customer object, so it's better to name it like so:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lentgth=200) 
    src_n_type = models.Foreign_key(source_of_enquiry)
    contact = models.CharField(max_lentgth=200)
```

You other fields can also be cleaner:

```
class SourceEnquiry(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

class SaleCycle(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    customer = models.Foreignkey(Customer)
```

Comment: Thanks @yuvi, I will definitely redo my models and follow naming conventions. i think my attempt in `select_related` and `prefetch_selected ` are useless, i need to understand doc more carefully , the answer is very simple and good , thanks

Comment: `select_related` and `prefetch_related` are performance boosters ment to [stop the deluge of database queries that is caused by accessing related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). Say if you fetch a bunch of objects and you want to avoid hitting the database for each one when fetching their related objects.